# Get value frome one table, to another based on the same value of 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've got one table with 3 columns, and another with 2 columns and I want to get value from table 1 to table2 if column 1 & column 2 values are the same as table2 column 1 & column 2.

[image]

As above, in table 2 I need to get values from table 1. Eg. Table 1 cat lion is 3, I want to copy 3 to each row in table 2 where cat lion is. Can it be achieved by formula or vba code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- VBA Code

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    ' Load table1 into an arraya
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Load data into Dict object
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2)
        objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 3)
    Next i
    ' Load table2
    Set rngData = Range("E2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2)
        If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then _
            arrData(i, 3) = objDic(sKey)
    Next i
    ' Write ouput to sheet
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Comment: This also works fine and Ive decided to use VBA code coz Ive already had table1 in scripting.dictionary. Instead of creating another one, Ive used my previous. Ive only had to add `VBA.VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare` before filling the dictionary. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(C$2:C$4,BYROW(A$2:B$4=$E2:$F2,AND))
```

---

Or,

```
=XLOOKUP(E2:E8&"|"&F2:F8,A2:A4&"|"&B2:B4,C2:C4,"")
```

---

Comment: Yes, concatenation should **never** be done without a proper delimiter. Preferably a workaround like your 1st option.

Comment: @JvdV Sir all learnt from you. 

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```cpp
=XLOOKUP(E2:E8&F2:F8,A2:A4&B2:B4,C2:C4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the value you want to get is a number like in your example, you may use SUMIFS:

[image]

Formula in cell I3 is:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$5;$A$3:$A$5;G3;$B$3:$B$5;H3)
```

Just drag down

Comment: Good use of `SUMIFS()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks! SUMIFS can be really useful and emulate functions like VLOOKUP and similar as far as target value is numeric. And it's pretty easy to apply criteria in SUMIFS. Works pretty good specially if you got unique values on criterias!